# What does "public App() : this(null) { }" do when using Xamarin Forms with Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

So I was jsut wondering why in the Prism Doc and VS template this line is included in the App Class.

`public App() : this(null) { }`

Since today I commented it out and the App still started without any issues in both iOs and Android.

Best Regards

Basecrusher

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need/want an `IPlatformInitializer`, it's fine to pass `null`, and the default implementation does so.

I guess the code is in there to remind you that you *could* pass an `IPlatformInitializer` if you needed/wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

"With Xamarin.Forms you may have read how you can add the Dependency attribute for an impelementing type in your Platform Specific code and then resolve it with the Xamarin.Forms DependencyService. This is considered a major Anti-Pattern that should be avoided when you are using a proper Dependency Injection container. It is for this reason that Prism has dropped all support for working with the DependencyService as of Prism 7.0. Starting with Prism 6.3 the IPlatformInitializer was introduced. This allows you to easily register types with Prism's container."

https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dependency-injection/platform-specific-services.html

Comment: You describe the "want/need" case of my answer, if you don't have platform-specific code, it's the "not need" case. If you're a freak and thrive on service locators, it's the "not want" case :-)

Comment: Yes, I agreed with you, I voted for your answer, I just wanted to supplement with the documentation.